# Is it possible to integrate Salesforce with SDL Tridion?

Tags: external-integrations

I would like to know how can we integrate SDL Tridion with Salesforce.com. The idea is to use the content developed by Tridion to use in self service portal in salesforce.com

Answer (score 11):

You have to be careful when you say "SalesForce" because it can mean a lot of different features... SalesForce is a series of apps and they all have different requirements.

Given that you mention "self-service portal" I assume you're looking into integrating with [Force.com](http://www.force.com), and for that I see a couple of possible solutions:

1. Expose an OData endpoint and consume it from force.com - they have rest connectors, and [APEX](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/) can use content delivered like this
2. Write a set of deployer extensions to deploy and undeploy to force, then consume the content "natively" in your APEX app.

We do expect developments in the integrations between Tridion and SFDC, but there's nothing in the current Tridion suite to give "out-of-the-box" integration.

Comment: +1 for suggesting oData; Tridion provides this integration API out-of-the-box and any application that can consume content over oData doesn't need a connector to Tridion specifically

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, direct out-of-the-box integration of SDL Tridion with Salesforce is not available. However, a custom solution can be built to achieve this by using SDL Tridion Extension Points and Salesforce APIs on the same note as you get Drupal's Salesforce Suite which allows to have an integration of Drupal with the Salesforce.

Comment: Can someone explain me the reason for downvote, so that I can take care in furture.

Comment: It was not me that down-voted your answer, but I suspect that it does not provide enough detail.  "Using SDL Tridion Extension Points" is very generic.  I think your answer could be improved by stating exactly which extensions point(s) could be used (as Nuno has above) and/or providing details about the SalesForce API or possible connection points.